# XOJO how to pass arguments to external executable

Tags: xojo

I need to open external exe file, and in the same time to pass some arguments to it.

The documentation in Xojo Library suggest to use the Shell, but I have not seen the practical example how to do it.

Xojo Shell command Explanation:

```
Dim sh As New Shell

sh.Execute("Location to a file")
```

I have tried the following:

```
sh.Execute("Location to a file" + " " + myArgumentOne + " " + myArgumentTwo)
```

There is no error, just the *.exe is not being run.

If there is solution using FolderItem, I would gladly use it as well.

Comment: If the `Location to a file` might contain spaces then you need to enclose it with quotation marks before passing it to `Shell.Execute`. ([See here](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/%22%22#Including_a_double_quote_inside_a_literal_string) for adding double quotes to string literals.) Otherwise, the shell will not be able to locate the executable. e.g. `sh.Execute("""Location to a file""" + " " + myArgumentOne + " " + myArgumentTwo)`

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to use a shell. When you have the folderitem, use Launch to execute the program and pass parameters. For instance

```
  dim f as folderitem = GetFolderItem("C:\myprogram.exe", Folderitem.PathTypeShell)
  f.Launch("Parameter1, Parameter2")
```

See http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/FolderItem.Launch

Answer (score 1):

```
sh.Execute F.ShellPath +"\program.exe " + parameters
```

F is a Folderitm pointing to the directory of the program and parameters is a string